# Is there no setting for AWS API Gateway REST API to disable execute-api endpoint in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have setup an API Gateway (v1, not v2) REST API resource using CloudFormation template. Recently I have noticed that the default execute-api endpoint is also created, which I can disable in the settings.

[image]
*The type of this API is `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`.*

Naturally, I would like this to be done through the template, so the question is: can this setting be defined in the CloudFormation template, rather than havign to be clicked manually in the AWS Console? This option **is available** for the APIGateway V2 API resource (`AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api`) but not the APIGateway V1 REST API resource (`AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`) in the CloudFormation templates, even though it can be changed  manuall for the APIGateway V1 REST API in the console.

There is also a [CLI way of doing this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-disable-default-endpoint.html) for the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`.

Here are some links I have used to search for this setting:
[AWS::ApiGatewayV2::API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html)
[AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html)
[Disabling default api-execute endpoint via CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-disable-default-endpoint.html)

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html) it is not supported in the Cloudformation definition. But there is an option in[RestAPI Create Call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/restapi-create/#disableExecuteApiEndpoint). If you really would like to do it in the CFN you can leverage [Running bash commands in AWS CloudFormation templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for disabling the default execute-api endpoint has recently been added to AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi cloudformation: [DisableExecuteApiEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-disableexecuteapiendpoint)

```
MyRestApi:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
  Properties:
    DisableExecuteApiEndpoint: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it though a simple [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html). Below is an example of such a **fully working** template that does that:

```
Resources:

  MyRestApi:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Description: A test API
      Name: MyRestAPI


  LambdaBasicExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  MyCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::DisableDefaultApiEndpoint
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt 'MyCustomFunction.Arn'
      APIId: !Ref 'MyRestApi'

  MyCustomFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Description: "Disable default API endpoint"
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaBasicExecutionRole.Arn'
      Runtime: python3.7
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import logging
          import cfnresponse
          import boto3
          
          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

          client = boto3.client('apigateway')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            logger.info('got event {}'.format(event))  
            try:

              responseData = {}

              if event['RequestType'] in ["Create"]:                      
                
                APIId = event['ResourceProperties']['APIId']                
                
                response = client.update_rest_api(
                    restApiId=APIId,
                    patchOperations=[
                        {
                            'op': 'replace',
                            'path': '/disableExecuteApiEndpoint',
                            'value': 'True'
                        }
                    ]
                )

                logger.info(str(response))

                cfnresponse.send(event, context, 
                                 cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)

              else:
                logger.info('Unexpected RequestType!') 
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, 
                                  cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)

            except Exception as err:

              logger.error(err)
              responseData = {"Data": str(err)}
              cfnresponse.send(event,context, 
                               cfnresponse.FAILED,responseData)
            return
```

Comment: @MarceliWac No problem .Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles across this answer that is using CDK, this can be done concisely (without defining a Lambda function) using the AwsCustomResource construct:

```
const restApi = new apigw.RestApi(...);
const executeApiResource = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, "execute-api-resource", {
  functionName: "disable-execute-api-endpoint",
  onCreate: {
    service: "APIGateway",
    action: "updateRestApi",
    parameters: {
      restApiId: restApi.restApiId,
      patchOperations: [{
        op: "replace",
        path: "/disableExecuteApiEndpoint",
        value: "True"
      }]
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of("execute-api-resource")
  },
  policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([new iam.PolicyStatement({
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: ["apigateway:PATCH"],
    resources: ["arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"],
  })])
});
executeApiResource.node.addDependency(restApi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in AWS CDK. This is done by finding the CloudFormation resource and setting it to true.

```
   const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'api', );
   (api.node.children[0] as apigateway.CfnRestApi).addPropertyOverride('DisableExecuteApiEndpoint','true')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python variant of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67384561/86924) provided by snorberhuis.

```
 rest_api = apigateway.RestApi(self,...)
 cfn_apigw = rest_api.node.default_child
 cfn_apigw.add_property_override('DisableExecuteApiEndpoint', True)
```

[Amazon's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) on "Abstractions and Escape Hatches" is very good for understanding what's going on here.